# Incorrect syntax inserting data into table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I am having some trouble with my `update()` method. The idea is that the user Provides a recipe name, ingredients, instructions and then selects an image using Filestream.

Once the user clicks 'Add Recipe' this will call the update method, however as things stand I am getting an error which is mentioning the contents of the text box:

[image]

Here is the update() method code:

```
 private void updatedata()

        { 
        // filesteam object to read the image
        // full length of image to a byte array

            try
            {
                // try to see if the image has a valid path

                if (imagename != "")
                {

                    FileStream fs;
                    fs = new FileStream(@imagename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                    // a byte array to read the image

                    byte[] picbyte = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                    fs.Close();

                    //open the database using odp.net and insert the lines

                    string connstr = @"Server=mypcname\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RecipeOrganiser;Trusted_Connection=True";

                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
                    conn.Open();
                    string query;
                    query = "insert into Recipes(RecipeName,RecipeImage,RecipeIngredients,RecipeInstructions) values (" + textBox1.Text + "," + " @pic" + "," + textBox2.Text + "," + textBox3.Text + ")";
                    SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter();
                    picparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
                    picparameter.ParameterName = "pic";
                    picparameter.Value = picbyte;
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(picparameter);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Image successfully saved");
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                    Connection();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong with the insert into Recipes query or suggest an alternative approach to this part of the code?

Comment: Please use parametrized queries..

Comment: Also stuffing all RecipeIngredients into a single column isn't a normalised design and you should use `using` blocks.

Comment: You're not quoting your text values. put a single quote(') before and after each value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is open to SQL Injection, but probably your error comes from some text that contains a single quote (the instructions fields for example) and this break your command string build using concatenating the user input.

**EDIT**
As someone pointed in comment the error is caused by the missing quotes around your textboxes. But while easy to fix that's not the way to go because it is wrong to fix the error adding the missing quotes. It is just postponig the problem leaving a big security hole waiting to be exploited.

A parameterized query could avoid all this mess.

```
  string connstr = "....";     
  string query = "insert into Recipes(RecipeName,RecipeImage,RecipeIngredients,RecipeInstructions) " + 
          "values (@name, @pic, @ing, @instr)";
  using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
  using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
  {
    conn.Open();
    SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter();
    picparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
    picparameter.ParameterName = "@pic";
    picparameter.Value = picbyte;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(picparameter);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textbox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ing", textbox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@instr", textbox3.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Image successfully saved");
  }
```

Comment: It comes from the lack of surrounding single quotes in this case. The phrase "Salmon Pasta" doesn't contain a single quote. They still should parameterise the other three values though.

Comment: Is there supposed to be two string query; declaration's as one has already been declared in the parent scope?

Answer (score 3):

Since you using string concatenations, you probably missed a quote or you put an extra quote or missed a comma or put extra comma etc etc....

Don't use this way!

Your error doesn't look obviously but you should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
query = "insert into Recipes(RecipeName,RecipeImage,RecipeIngredients,RecipeInstructions) values (@p1, @pic, @p3, @p4)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@p1, textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@pic, textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@p3, textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@p4, picparameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

query = "insert into Recipes(RecipeName,RecipeImage,RecipeIngredients,RecipeInstructions) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "'," + " @pic" + ",'" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')";